# A singleton is created when a collection-type dependency property is assigned a value

Tags: wpf, singleton, dependency-properties

I am attempting to create a dependency object in WPF of type List(Of) containing all the children of the control. Despite taking precautions outlined   [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970563.aspx) it seems that a singleton is created when I assign a value to the property. When I assign a value the value is added multiplied by the number of instances of the class.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Period
Inherits ListBox

'-------- PROPERTIES --------'
Private Property Subjects() As List(Of Subject)
    Get
        Return Me.GetValue(SubjectsProperty)
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of Subject))
        Me.SetValue(SubjectsProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Private Shared ReadOnly SubjectsProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Subjects", GetType(List(Of Subject)), GetType(Period), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(New List(Of Subject))) 

Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New()
            Me.Subjects = New List(Of Subject) 'Reason: stop it from adding values to defult value collection. See:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970563.aspx
End Sub
```

This subroutine is used to refresh the property when a child is added:

```
 Private Sub RefreshSubjectsProperty()
    Dim ListOfSubjects As New List(Of Subject)
    Dim Subject As New Subject
    Dim Entry As New PeriodEntry

    For Each Entry In LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(Me)
        Subject.SubjectName = Entry.SubjectName
        Subject.Teacher = Entry.Teacher
        Subject.Students = Entry.Students

        ListOfSubjects.Add(Subject)
    Next

    Me.Subjects = ListOfSubjects
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the problem? I don't it. If you define an dependency property of type collection with a default value like you did then you will always have a singleton instance. That is by design in WPF. Set the default value to null in property declaration and initalize the property in constructor to only use the property per dependency object.

Comment: @ninjahedgehog Thanks, I didnt realise that, I was just following the example on the MSDN website. Thanks.